# Select2 autocomplete does not populate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 autocomplete control on my MVC razor page. But I'm failing to populate Select2 when the user type something in the search box, the search box keeps on saying 'Searching..'. The web api returns the information, I'm able to see it in processResults function. Please assist.

**Razor/MVC**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label class="control-label labelFont">Add SimplyBiz member</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.DropDownList("multiselect_autocomplete", new MultiSelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()), new { @class = "autocomplete-members" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
$(".autocomplete-members").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: '@(Url.Action("MultipleMemberSearchAutoComplete"))',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                term: params.term// search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            console.log("on process results");
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function (index, option) {
                console.log("option");
                console.log(option);
                console.log(option.memberid + ' - ' + option.name);
                $('#multiselect_autocomplete').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', option.memberid).text(option.label).attr('title', option.name));
            });
    
            return {
                results: data.items
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you also share data sample?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to populate options manually - `Select2` automatically handles creating the new option elements when you return your results. All you need is  map your data items into acceptable format. Make sure you `data.items` is array of objects with `id` and `text` props (see https://select2.org/data-sources/formats)

Here is the sample

```
$(".autocomplete-members").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: '@(Url.Action("MultipleMemberSearchAutoComplete"))',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                term: params.term// search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.label,
                        id: item.memberid
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried this, but the control becomes read only, i can't type anything in the search box. I want it to populate the items when i start typing something.

Comment: Can you check errors in browser console?

Comment: Could you clarify when it becomes read-only? Before or after results returned?

Comment: It shows a message that says enter 3 or more characters, but it doesn't allow me to enter these characters.

Comment: are you sure that this effect related to ajax sourcing? try remove `minimumInputLength: 3` constrains and test